# Explicit S-duality map

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, duality

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Th}{Th}$
The Thom space of a closed manifold $M$ ($\Th(M)$) is the $S$-dual to $M_+ (=M \cup \{pt\})$. Let $M$ be embedded in $\mathbf R^{n+k}$. I found the duality map from  $S^{n+k} \to \Th(M)\sharp M_+$ in a note by J. Klein.
($\sharp$ identifies the smash product in our context here)

1. How do I get the other way map? Is it possible to compute from the given map?
2. If my manifold $M$ has trivial normal bundle, then $\Th(M)=M_+ \sharp S^k$. Is it possible that the above duality map is some suspension of a duality map, $S^n \to M_+ \sharp M_+$?

Thank you. Moreover, it is not necessary but it would be helpful if you attach any useful reference to your answers.

Comment: Certainly I am not the first to come up with this, but Theorem 2.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.05947 describes an explicit duality pairing $M_+ \wedge M^+ \rightarrow S^n$ for a framed $n$-manifold $M$. For a general manifold, one may apply this theorem to the total space of the normal bundle of $M$. The result is a duality pairing which is about as explicit as whatever your description of the normal bundle is.

Comment: @ConnorMalin So, it is like for each point of M, choosing degree one collapse map around them but choosing it continuously.

Comment: Yes that's right.